# writa and read the same line from a file in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying to

1. Check if  file exists
   ==> if file does not exist, Write values "0,0" in the file if it is a new file
2. Read the first line of the file

The problem I have is, once the line is written, I have to read the same line again to check for something. But the pointer moves on the next line. So how do I do this?

```
 File f1 = new File(DirPath);
 FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(DirPath);
 BufferedReader brTest = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
 if (brTest.readLine() == null) {
          printData = 0 + "," + 0;
          p.println(printData);

  }
  line = brTest.readLine(); // I have to read the line I wrote i.e 0, 0


     text = brTest .readLine();
```

Comment: Easiest method is to *not* re-read a file while writing it. While seek'ing can be used this can become very problematic very quickly because lines will *not* 'automatically shift'.

Comment: so should i close and open the file again to move it back to the begining?